# MITMProxy: smart URL replacement

Tags: python, mitmproxy

We use a custom scraper that have to take a separate website for a language (this is an architecture limitation). Like site1.co.uk, site1.es, site1.de etc.

But we need to parse a website with many languages, separated by url - like site2.com/en, site2.com/de, site2.com/es and so on.

I thought about MITMProxy: I could redirect all requests this way:

```
en.site2.com/* --> site2.com/en
de.site2.com/* --> site2.com/de
...
```

I have written a small script which simply takes URLs and rewrites them:

```
class MyMaster(flow.FlowMaster):

  def handle_request(self, r):
    url = r.get_url()

    # replace URLs
    if 'blabla' in url:
      r.set_url(url.replace('something', 'another'))
```

But the target host generates 301 redirect with the response from the webserver - 'the page has been moved here' and the link to the site2.com/en

It worked when I played with URL rewriting, i.e. site2.com/en --> site2.com/de.
But for different hosts (subdomain and the root domain, to be precise), it does not work.

I tried to replace the Host header in the handle_request method from above:

```
for key in r.headers.keys():
        if key.lower() == 'host':
            r.headers[key] = ['site2.com']
```

also I tried to replace the Referrer - all of that didn't help.

How can I finally spoof that request from the subdomain to the main domain? If it generates a HTTP(s) client warning it's ok since we need that for the scraper (and the warnings there can be turned off), not the real browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the content of the response and craft the header with just a few fields.
Open a new connection to the redirected url and craft your response :

```
def handle_request(self, flow):
  newUrl = <new-url>
  retryCount = 3
  newResponse = None
  while True:
    try:
      newResponse = requests.get(newUrl) # import requests
    except: 
      if retryCount == 0:
        print 'Cannot reach new url ' + newUrl
        traceback.print_exc() # import traceback
        return

      retryCount -= 1
      continue
    break

  responseHeaders = Headers() # from netlib.http import Headers

  if 'Date' in newResponse.headers:
    responseHeaders['Date'] = str(newResponse.headers['Date'])
  if 'Connection' in newResponse.headers:
    responseHeaders['Connection'] = str(newResponse.headers['Connection'])
  if 'Content-Type' in newResponse.headers:
    responseHeaders['Content-Type'] = str(newResponse.headers['Content-Type'])
  if 'Content-Length' in newResponse.headers:
    responseHeaders['Content-Length'] = str(newResponse.headers['Content-Length'])
  if 'Content-Encoding' in newResponse.headers:
    responseHeaders['Content-Encoding'] = str(inetResponse.headers['Content-Encoding'])

  response = HTTPResponse(   # from libmproxy.models import HTTPResponse
    http_version='HTTP/1.1',
    status_code=200,
    reason='OK',
    headers=responseHeaders,
    content=newResponse.content)

  flow.reply(response)
```