# Change URL to another URL using mitmproxy

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I am trying to redirect one page to another by using mitmproxy and Python. I can run my inline script together with mitmproxy without issues, but I am stuck when it comes to changing the URL to another URL. Like if I went to google.com it would redirect to stackoverflow.com

```
def response(context, flow):
        print("DEBUG")
        if flow.request.url.startswith("http://google.com/"):
            print("It does contain it")
            flow.request.url = "http://stackoverflow/"
```

This should in theory work. I see `http://google.com/` in the GUI of mitmproxy (as GET) but the `print("It does contain it")` never gets fired.

When I try to just put `flow.request.url = "http://stackoverflow.com"` right under the `print("DEBUG")` it won't work neither.

What am I doing wrong? I have also tried `if "google.com" in flow.request.url` to check if the URL contains `google.com` but that won't work either.

Thanks

Comment: (1) Do you see the “DEBUG” output? (2) Is your request actually `http://` or is it `https://`?

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov I see the "DEBUG" output yes (I have a separate print function, which writes to a file, which I then `tail -f` on, since mitmproxy's GUI fills the whole terminal). It is `http://` and I have carefully copy-pasted the entire URL from the mitmproxy GUI, so it matches 100%. Obviously google.com and stackoverflow.com are just fillers.

Comment: Alternative answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886372/mitmproxy-smart-url-replacement/35058400#35058400

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following `mitmproxy` script will

1. Redirect requesto from `mydomain.com` to `newsite.mydomain.com`
2. Change the request method path (supposed to be something like `/getjson?` to a new one `/getxml
3. Change the destination host scheme
4. Change the destination server port
5. Overwrite the request header `Host` to pretend to be the origi

   ```
   import mitmproxy
   from mitmproxy.models import HTTPResponse
   from netlib.http import Headers
   def request(flow):

       if flow.request.pretty_host.endswith("mydomain.com"):
               mitmproxy.ctx.log( flow.request.path )
               method = flow.request.path.split('/')[3].split('?')[0]
               flow.request.host = "newsite.mydomain.com"
               flow.request.port = 8181
               flow.request.scheme = 'http'
               if method == 'getjson':
                   flow.request.path=flow.request.path.replace(method,"getxml")
               flow.request.headers["Host"] = "newsite.mydomain.com"
   ```

Comment: do you have any url / documentation for mitmproxy how to use custom modules like this one ?

Comment: @AshfaqAhmed take a look at https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `url` attribute will not help you, as it is merely constructed from underlying data. [**EDIT:** I was wrong, see Maximilian’s answer. The rest of my answer should still work, though.]

Depending on what exactly you want to accomplish, there are two options.

(1) You can send an actual HTTP [redirection response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4) to the client. Assuming that the client understands HTTP redirections, it will submit a **new** request to the URL you give it.

```
from mitmproxy.models import HTTPResponse
from netlib.http import Headers

def request(context, flow):
    if flow.request.host == 'google.com':
        flow.reply(HTTPResponse('HTTP/1.1', 302, 'Found',
                                Headers(Location='http://stackoverflow.com/',
                                        Content_Length='0'),
                                b''))
```

(2) You can silently route the *same* request to a different host. The client will not see this, it will assume that it’s still talking to `google.com`.

```
def request(context, flow):
    if flow.request.url == 'http://google.com/accounts/':
        flow.request.host = 'stackoverflow.com'
        flow.request.path = '/users/'
```

These snippets were adapted from [an example](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/redirect_requests.py) found in mitmproxy’s own GitHub repo. There are [many more examples](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/tree/master/examples) there.

For some reason, I can’t seem to make these snippets work for Firefox when used **with TLS** (`https://`), but maybe you don’t need that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! All I need is make the content of X look like the content of Y. So if I enter `website.com` on the device connected, it should show the content of `another-website.com`. Changing the host as written in your other example won't work, as I need the whole URL to change. `google.com/account` works but `stackoverflow.com/account` doesn't. Get what I mean? I need to replace a whole URL to another URL.

Comment: @Snorlax Method (2) replaces the host in every requested URL. It does work for me. I’m using `example.com` and `stackoverflow.com`, and when I go to `http://example.com/users` in Firefox, I do actually see the Stack Overflow users page, with (relative) links pointing to other `example.com` pages. Maybe you can tell the actual sites you’re using? For example, if your `stackoverflow.com` depends on cookies, method (2) may not work, because the browser will not send `stackoverflow.com` cookies to `google.com`—but I don’t think you can do anything about that.

Comment: Oh, do you mean that you need to change the path in addition to the host? That’s easy, just set `flow.request.path` to whatever you want.

Comment: The problem with replacing `flow.request.host` is the paths need to be exactly the same. I don't want that. I want to be able to say `if url == "example.com": url = "new-example.com`. I know it's possible, I just don't know how.

Comment: Still not good enough. I need to change an EXACT URL to another EXACT URL. `anything-goes-here.com/anything-123.html -> google.com/account` for example.

Comment: @Snorlax An HTTP/1.1 request (to a server) does not include the full URL. It has a host and a path, separately. If you need a way to split `http://google.com/account` into a host and a path, then use [`urlparse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse).

Comment: So basically I would check if `flow.request.host.get_url()` is equal to my X URL, then I would set the host and the path afterwards, which is essentially like doing X->Y?

Comment: @Snorlax Exactly. But, as I said, depending on the site, there may be caveats like cookies, `localStorage`, XHR requests becoming cross-origin, etc., that would prevent the resulting page from rendering correctly.

Comment: This will not be an issue. All I basically need to do, is change one JSON page (`file.json`) into another JSON page, but it's a bit more advanced than **just** doing that, as I need to make it user based.

Comment: Oh yeah I will definitely do that, but I need to reinstall my server. For some reason, mitmproxy keeps screwing up. Like I can't find `mitmproxy.models`. I did do `sudo pip install mitmproxy`, but I guess I'll have to go and compile it all from source. So far I think this sounds like a working plan! Do you know `--hypasswd` works? I got it to work and all that, but do you know how to read the username? Like `if username == "something": set path to something else`

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot for the help! Do you know if it's possible to get the current user sending the request though?

Comment: @Snorlax I suggest you post that as a separate question, this comment thread is too long already.

Comment: I agree. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `.url` attribute, which [will update the underlying attributes](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/9d47d3b1ecaed6db1d143a56973e931140ad1949/netlib/http/request.py#L186). Looking at your code, your problem is that you change the URL in the `response` hook, after the request has been done. You need to change the URL in the `request` hook, so that the change is applied before requesting resources from the upstream server.

Comment: I did try to set the `.url` "attribute" in the request hook as well, but it did not really seem to work either.